# What are the different types of fishing locations?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Animal Crossing has always had different fish spawn in different bodies of water, and at different times of days. For example, you'll catch different fish in the **River** versus  the **Sea**. However, New Horizons has added some new ones, such as **River (Clifftop)**.

Since there's always some fish that are can only be caught in a specific area (i.e.  *Stringfish* is only available in **River (Clifftop)**), it would be really helpful to know the different areas I should be making sure to frequently check for fish (or that it would actually be helpful to toss bait into).

What are all the different types of fishing locations that fish can spawn in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complete list of possible fishing locations is as follows:

- River

  - River (Clifftop) - which includes all rivers at least 1 level above sea level
  - River (Mouth) - which includes the portion of the river surrounded by sand
- Sea

  - Sea (Rain) - not really a different *location* per se but one fish does specifically require rain
- Pond
- Pier

Comment: Do you know if Pier includes the Airport Pier as well? Or does it only include that solo pier, without a plane?

Comment: @Wipqozn I believe it includes the airport pier on mystery islands, but I don't think you can fish from the airport pier on your island.